# Why the @State value is not updated

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have three buttons, each button corresponds to a value in the data array. When user click a button, the corresponding value will be displayed in a sheet window. Here's my code:

```
struct TestView: View {
    @State var data: [Int] = [100, 200, 300]
    @State var presented: Bool = false
    @State var index4edit: Int = 1
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack{
            ForEach(1..<4){ index in
                Button(action: {
                    index4edit = index
                    presented.toggle()
                }){ Text(String(index)) }
                .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                .padding()
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $presented, content: {
            Text("\(index4edit): \(data[index4edit-1])")
        })
    }
}
```

My problem is, the first time I click a button, no matter which button, it's always display the first data `100`. The reason is that the data `index4edit` was not updated on the first click, it is always `1`, but why? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because sheet view is created on View initalization. When you change your State, your view won't be recreated because your State variable is not used in your view.

To solve it, just use your State variable somewhere in the code like this dummy example

```
HStack{
    ForEach(1..<4){ index in
        Button(action: {
            index4edit = index
            presented.toggle()
        }){ Text(String(index) + (index4edit == 0 ? "" : "")) } //<<here is the State used
        .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Now you view will rerender when the State changes, hence your sheet view will be rerendered.

Comment: Thank you. To avoid use it somewhere, I make it as a static variable.

Answer (score 0):

You should set up `index4edit` to be the real (0-based) index, not index + 1. You should also use `data.indices` in the `ForEach` instead of manually inputting the range.

```
struct TestView: View {
    @State private var data: [Int] = [100, 200, 300]
    @State private var presented: Bool = false
    @State private var index4edit: Int = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            ForEach(data.indices) { index in
                Button(action: {
                    index4edit = index
                    presented.toggle()
                }){ Text(String(index)) }
                .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                .padding()
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $presented, content: {
            Text("\(index4edit): \(data[index4edit])")
        })
    }
}

struct TestView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but not work, still `100` always.

Comment: @Mandroid how are you creating the `TestView`? I did test this in a preview and it works like charm.

Comment: @Mandroid I meant what's the actual code you use. If you used the code from my answer, it would work, so there must be another issue with your code.

Comment: Just copy / paste your code. This problem only occurs when click the button for the first time after running.